# print largest number out of 4 numbers optimize

Tags: c++, optimization, logic

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1,num2,num3,num4;
    int x;
    int y;
    cin>>num1>>num2>>num3>>num4;
    if (num1 > num2)

    {
         x=num1;
    }
    else
        {x = num2;
        }
    if(num3>num4)
        {y = num3;
        }
    else
    {
        y= num4;
    } 
    if (x>y)
    {cout<<"the largest number is:"<<x;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"the largest number is :"<<y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code to print largest number out of 4 numbers.
the question is that i am asked to  optimize or compact the solution.
i tried but could not find another way to write such program.Can any one help me to optimize the solution and make it better..
ignore syntax errors..

Comment: To compact the source code, put all 4 values in an array.  Then inside a for loop check the current champion against the current element.  Keep whichever is higher.  Leave the loop after 4 rounds and output the winner.  You can actually do it without any other variables at all.  if (num[i]>num[0]) num[0]=num[i].  Then after the loop cout << num[0];

Comment: Hint: Use a `std::vector<int>` to store the numbers and lookup for the largest in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x, m;
    cin >> x;
    m = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        cin >> x;
        m = m > x ? m : x;
    }

    cout << "The largest number is: " << m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Use loops.

Comment: I'd recommend against using `max` as a variable name.  That shadows the STL `max` function (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) which many readers of your code would expect to see.  You can still use it as `std::max`, but I think it's still poor style.  +1 for putting the i/o in the loop to process data on the fly as you read it.

Comment: @PeterCordes usually I don't use `using namespace std;`, so I haven't thought about it

Comment: Even without `using namespace std`, I'd still recommend against using `max` or `min` as var names.  I'm not sure what current C++ style guides would have to say, though;  I usually look at C, not C++.

Answer (score 5):

Could be as simple as this:

```
int max = std::max( std::max( num1, num2 ), std::max( num3, num4 ) );
```

Comment: You are using max as variable name and as a function call. How does C++ distinguish between these two max?

Comment: @MoizSajid The function is in the `std` namespace, the variable isn't.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to store the values in an array and iterate over it:

```
int num[4];    
cin >> num[0] >> num[1] >> num[2] >> num[3];

int max = num[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) {
    if (num[i] > max) {
        max = num[i];
    }
}
cout << "The largest number is:" << max << endl;
```

Comment: is there any other approach if i am not allowed to use an array

Comment: @HassaanElahi That's a requirement you should have placed in the question--without informing users that their tools are limited they're going to reach for the most effective one.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you may directly do

```
const int biggest = std::max({num1, num2, num3, num4});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)) in this case i do not use std library. Just use an if-else statement like below. if(a > b) then return a else b.
Other case, we can create an array and request input to the user. First we set the first element in this array is MAX value. Use a loop and check. if current element is larger than MAX then we update the MAX value to the current value.

```
int maxOfTwoNumber(int a, int b){ return a>b? a : b; }
int maxOfFourNumber(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    return maxOfTwoNumber(maxOfTwoNumber(a, b), maxOfTwoNumber(c, d));
}
```

Comment: And why not using `std::max` ?

Comment: In this case i do not use std library :)